# Trackpad suddenly stopped working (Razer Blade Stealth, 18.04)

Tags: touchpad

My trackpad suddenly stopped working today -- currently typing from a live USB install, where my trackpad works fine.

How should I go about debugging/fixing this issue?

I've done some poking around and found that when I cat `/proc/bus/input/device` my trackpad shows up with event16, but when I look at my Xorg log it shows the trackpad as being under event11. On my current live USB these two event numbers are the same. Is this a problem?

Thanks in advance!